# Google Docs App Script Get Put Heading of Section into Header

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-docs, google-docs-api

I am writing a book using Google Docs and trying to put the heading of each page into the header of the specific page.

I did not find a way to have different headers on different pages. The header section seems to be static for all pages except for the first one.

I am wondering if there is a way to dynamically change the heading based on the heading of a page and if someone already has experiences with that topic.

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/docs#structure_of_a_document),

> There are rules about which types of elements can contain other types. Furthermore, the Document Service in Apps Script can only insert certain types of elements.

[HeaderSection](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/header-section) is one of those elements that can only be manipulated in place.